# How to display a text on top of all page in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I have a requirement to display a text on top of the page (Home page and other pages as well) right next to the site title in sharepoint 2013.

Can anyone provide suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options.

The first option is to update the master page used in the site(s) where you wanted to add the text. Updates to the master page can be made using SharePoint Designer or in Visual Studio.

The second option is to use a ScriptLink to inject JavaScript that would add the text in the target site(s). The definition of the ScriptLink and the deployment of the JavaScript would be done in Visual Studio.